# Unable to link my App with the Google AdMob

Tags: ios

My app is ready for sale on the App Store but, on the Google AdMob I can't link my App as it says it will take a few days before it is showed up on the the list at Google AdMob. I wanted to ask whether I can still distribute my app to people and still see the ad analytics. Or will it affect the my ad earnings if I don't link it with my iOS app? Also it won't lead to blocking of my Google AdMob account right? Thanks for the help!